# ORDER BY CASE in mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have been checking out the forum a lot for this question but as I am just a beginner I could not find an answer that I could use to my code work with my little knowledge. This is what I am trying to solve:

I have many products in my shop. There are 4 different types.

1. product_name starts with "AA-"
2. product_name starts with "BB-"
3. product_name starts with "CC-"
4. product_name starts with "DF-"

No when I expose the products to the viewer I want to use ORDER BY ASC.

But with product "CC-" en "DF-" I want it to be ordered DESC.

And if my product_name starts with "BB-" it should be ordered by price ( which is also called in the select statement )

I learned I should use CASE for this. But I don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also go with **UNION** in this case easily, like this :

```
select t1.product_name Name, t1.product_price Price from

 (select product_name, product_price from shop 
  where product_name like 'cc%' or product_name like 'de%'
  order by product_name desc) t1

 union 

 select t2.* from
 ( select  product_name, product_price from shop 
   where product_name like 'bb%'
   order by product_price ) t2

 union 

 select t3.* from
 ( select product_name, product_price from shop 
   where ( product_name not like 'cc%') and ( product_name not like 'de%')
   and (product_name not like 'bb%') 
   order by  product_name, product_price) t3 ;
```